# It is possible to format a text with a key=argument that starts with a number?

Tags: python, string, format

```
text = "Today I went to the {1N}".format(1N="zoo")
```

Comment: `1N` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: Keyword arguments have to be a valid Python identifier, so not starting with a number. You could pass a dictionary: `format(**{'1N':"zoo"})` but it's probably easier to use a valid identifier.

Comment: No. Suggestion: you can use `_1N`

Answer (score 1):

Keyword arguments have to be a valid Python identifier, so not starting with a number.

You could pass a dictionary with the `**` operator:

```
"Today I went to the {1N}".format(**{'1N':"zoo"})
```

but it's probably easier to use a valid identifier instead.